# Node - set angular-cli environment

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm deploying my angular-cli app through node. Rather than `ng serve --prod`, I use `npm start`.

Is there any way to achieve the `--environment=prod` setting from npm so that it will use `environment.prod.ts` instead of `environment.ts`?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Top of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "asgard2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
[...]
```

To start in production, I can run:

```
ng serve --prod
```

But I can't do:

```
npm start --prod
```

Or at least, when I do, it is still deployed as debug. It is very likely that I am doing something wrong in my deployment.

Comment: Unclear. What does your npm start script does?

Comment: @JBNizet: Everything is default as set up by angular-cli, but you make a very good point. I should probably build first, then deploy and serve.

Comment: Ah, so you want npm start to do `ng serve --prod` instead of the default `ng serve`? Just edit your package.json and add `--prod` after `ng serve`.

Comment: @JBNizet: Well. I actually wanted to avoid using the NG Live Development Server due to the warning to not use it in production, so I'm trying to deploy the angular-cli app to Node.js via docker. As I don't have 'ng' available there, I wanted to start it in another way. There may be something I don't understand along the way. A lot of new stuff to learn.

Comment: So you want to deploy your application to a real, production web server. Use `ng build --prod`. That generates a set of static files under the dist directory, that can be served by any web server able to serve static files. Install a production web server (like Apache, or Nginx for example) in your docker container, and make it serve those static files. You can also use a node-based web server if you want, but if the goal is just to serve static files, I don't really see the point, and Apache or Nginx will probably be more efficient.

Comment: @JBNizet: That makes perfect sense. I'm not even sure why I thought that the docker container should be building anything. As for node.js, I actually thought that was more lightweight than nginx, but since I'm already using nginx as a reverse proxy, I'll just spin up a new container based on that. Thanks! If you make an answer, I will accept that.

Comment: I'm not a NodeJS expert, but Node is not a web server. It's a JavaScript runtime environment, which has an API, and libraries, to run web applications. You would still need to write code, or at least configure and start a server like express, to serve your files.

Comment: @JBNizet: Upon brief study, it seems you are right. I got lost in the seemingly thousands of new libraries/frameworks associated with Angular development :D

Comment: I know the feeling. Been there for a few years now, and I'm still not completely comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to deploy your application to a real, production web server.

Use `ng build --prod`. That generates a set of static files under the `dist` directory, that can be served by any web server able to serve static files.

Install a production web server (like Apache, or Nginx for example) in your docker container, and make it serve those static files.

You can also use a node-based web server if you want, but if the goal is just to serve static files, I don't really see the point, and Apache or Nginx will probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could go into your environment.ts file and change

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

to

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

Comment: But then I'd have the reverse prod when not in production. I guess I could copy the contents of environment.ts to environment.prod.ts during deployment.